# How to show the types of each declaraion of a ocaml program?

Tags: types, ocaml

I like to use `ocaml` in a terminal to get interactive result or type from each ocaml command, for instance:

```
        Objective Caml version 3.11.2

# let a = 5;;
val a : int = 5
```

But when there are many commands, it is normal that we put all in a file like `test.ml`, then compile it. At the moment, I use `ocamlc -o test test.ml`. But when I do `test` in a terminal, I could not see the types of each declaration, which is a pity.

Does anyone know how to show that? Thank you very much.

Comment: You also don't mention whether you are on a Unix-like system or not, but something to keep in mind is: `test` is a standard binary in `/bin`.  Thus you probably want to run your generated executable with `./test` or else you'll accidentally be running the wrong thing.

Comment: Regardless, you cannot print out the type information by executing a compiled file; the intention was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toplevel you can load the entire file by, `#use "filename"`, and this is similar to typing directly into the top-level.

For compiling, you can generate the the type information by adding the `-i` option to the compiler. This will print the defined names to standard out, which can be piped to a file for a quick and dirty way to generate an mli file.

For more detailed type information you can add the `-annot` option, which will print the type, scope, and tail-call information for *every* label in the file. It would have to be parsed since it isn't directly obvious from the file what is happening. There are plugins for emacs and vim, and probably eclipse, that can do this for you.

Tools to help in ocaml type annotations were discussed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981620/see-inferred-types-in-complex-ocaml-code).

Comment: Thanks for your help... I tried `ocamlc -o test test.ml -annot -i`, but it is odd that there is no `test.mli` or `test.annot` generated.

Comment: Also, `#use test.ml;;` returns `Error: Unbound value use`, where `test.ml` only contains one line: `let a = 5;;`, which is quite strange...

Comment: 1) not sure 2) it is #use, not use. I know the prompt is #, so that could be confusing.

Comment: Also, you have to put quotes around the file name, so the entire line you should look like this: `# #use "test.ml";;`