# How to generate and set up annotation for Ocaml in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, makefile, annotations, compilation, ocaml

I am writing a compiler in Ocaml with Emacs. I am told that with `-annot` a file `.annot` could be generated while compiling, which could help Emacs to show the type of my code. But it is odd that no `.annot` is generated after running this [makefile](http://paste.ubuntu.com/630374/). Could anyone tell me what is wrong with that?

Also, once i have got `.annot`, do I need to set up anything (for instance `.emacs`?) so that my Emacs read it and show the type of my code?

Thank you very much!

Edit1: after `make clean` and `make`, I have got the `.annot`... But I still do not know how to make use of this `.annot` in Emacs.

Edit2: actually it is necessary to follow this [link](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/poly/emacs/index.html), copy the files in a local folder, then update `.emacs`. Then when a `.ml` is edited in Emacs, C-c C-t returns its type from `.annot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your emacs inquiry --I don't use emacs--, this is from the [man-pages](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual022.html) for `ocamlc`,

> -annot      Dump detailed information about the compilation (types, bindings, tail-calls, etc). The information for file src.ml is put into file src.annot.  In case of a type error, dump all the information inferred by the type-checker before the error. The src.annot file can be used with the emacs commands given in emacs/caml-types.el to display types and other annotations interactively.

There are also other tools from [the thread I mentioned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388803/how-to-show-the-types-of-each-declaraion-of-a-ocaml-program).

As for the `Makefile` not creating the `.annot` files, I made a mock directory and successfully had `.annot` files created. I also don't see anything wrong with your `Makefile`. You may want to clean the directory and try again, or switch to another way to build your tool like `ocamlbuild` --which would require minimal setup, although, I haven't used it with `menhir`.

I will also note that [`-annot` is new since OCaml 3.11.0](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-3.11/notes/Changes), and prior the flag was `-dtypes`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I edited above, I do generate `.annot`, but I still do not see how to make use of it...

Comment: You'll have to be more specific since the links I referenced for you should have explained that.

Comment: That link is unnecessary and could very well become out of date. The emacs folder discussed in the man pages and elsewhere is released with the ocaml distribution. Or possibly as an additional package as part of your package-manager (in ubuntu, `ocaml-mode`; alternatively `tuareg-mode`).